# EveryPlay Unity Video Recording - Live recording steam display on top right

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, everyplay

Unity game with everyplay video recording integration
Device: Android Nexus 5

Recording works fine in my game and able to share video on everyplay/facebook/youtube.

Problem:
When recording is on. Everyplay shows a live recording preview on top right of my screen. This problem is transient and mostly occur first time I run my application. I am not using any Facecam related features in my application. Side preview show live feed of recording. I do not want to suffer the performance. What's the best way to ensure that facecam features are turned off?

Answer (score 0):

For the community. My problem got resolved.

Repro Steps:
Android device - Nexus 5 kitkat
1) Record the video
2) Open share dialog
3) Click on video to play it
4) Don't watch complete video and press back button to come back to game
5) Start recording video again in the game. Gap between 4-5 should be minimal say 1-2 second
6) Video will not record as Everyplay was not ready for recording yet - This is okay.
7) You will also see small previous video preview feed on top right corner of your game.

Resolution:
Wait for Everyplay to get ready for recording before calling startrecording again.